# Controlling Stepper motor using RC receiver

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper, stepper-motor

I am using Arduino UNO with a DM556 Micro step driver to control the Stepper motor.

PUL+ --> pin 3

DIR+ --> pin 5

RC receiver --> pin 2

Using CH2 of receiver

With out the RC receiver (R9SX) everything works fine, the motor works perfectly. However I cannot figure out how to control it with RC. I tried to find a tutorial using Micro step driver but everybody appears to use Arduino Nano or some other equipment.

The code I am using makes the motor work extremely slow and only in one direction.

I'd really appreciate it if some one can point error in my code or provide me with a suitable one for my use case.

CODE:

```
// Define Pins
#define RCPin 2
#define DIR 5
#define STEP 3

// Set up time variables for Stepper motor
unsigned long previousMotorTime = millis();
long MotorInterval;

// Set up time variables for RC Read
volatile long Pulses = 0;
int PulseWidth = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // RC Read Setup
  pinMode(RCPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RCPin), PulseTimer, CHANGE); 

  // Set DIR and STEP pins to OUTPUT
  pinMode(DIR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(STEP, OUTPUT);

  // Set initial direction (LOW = one direction, HIGH = the other direction)
  digitalWrite(DIR, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(STEP, LOW);

  // Only save HIGH pulse lengths
  if (Pulses < 2000){
    PulseWidth = Pulses;
  }

  // Stepper motor speed, bigger MotorInterval is a slower speed.
  if (PulseWidth >= 1400 && PulseWidth <= 1600) {
    digitalWrite(STEP, LOW); // Motor doesn't move if the joystick is near the midpoint
  } else if (PulseWidth < 1400) {
    digitalWrite(DIR, LOW);
    MotorInterval = map(PulseWidth, 1000, 1400, 1, 25); // Map the RC signal to the motor speed in reverse when the joystick is pulled down
  } else if (PulseWidth > 1600) {
    digitalWrite(DIR, HIGH);
    MotorInterval = map(PulseWidth, 1600, 1984, 25, 1); // Map the RC signal to the motor speed when the joystick is pushed forward.
  }
  
  // Check if the MotorInterval time has elapsed and step the motor.
  unsigned long currentMotorTime = millis(); 
  if (currentMotorTime - previousMotorTime > MotorInterval) {
    digitalWrite(STEP, HIGH);
    previousMotorTime = currentMotorTime;
  }
}

// Function to measure the length of the pulses from the remote control
void PulseTimer() {
  static long StartTime = 0;
  long CurrentTime = micros();
  if (CurrentTime > StartTime) {
    Pulses = CurrentTime - StartTime;
    StartTime = CurrentTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a spec sheet for your motor?

Comment: reduce your program to only the minimal code required to spin the motor in one direction at the highest speed ... does it turn fast enough?

Comment: I used some other sketch to check this and it works great.